# replacing part of a string with value from another column

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

A pandas DataFrame contains a column with descriptions and placeholders in curly braces:

```
descr                        replacement
This: {should be replaced}   with this
```

The task is to replace the text in the curly braces with text from another column in the same row. It's unfortunately not as easy as:

```
df["descr"] = df["descr"].str.replace(r"{*?}", df["replacement"])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in replace(self, pat, repl, n, case, flags, regex)
   2532     def replace(self, pat, repl, n=-1, case=None, flags=0, regex=True):
   2533         result = str_replace(self._parent, pat, repl, n=n, case=case,
-> 2534                              flags=flags, regex=regex)
   2535         return self._wrap_result(result)
   2536 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in str_replace(arr, pat, repl, n, case, flags, regex)
    548     # Check whether repl is valid (GH 13438, GH 15055)
    549     if not (is_string_like(repl) or callable(repl)):
--> 550         raise TypeError("repl must be a string or callable")
    551 
    552     is_compiled_re = is_re(pat)

TypeError: repl must be a string or callable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is using the [Pandas.Series.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and it expects two strings to perform the replacement operation, but the second parameter is a Series.

> **Series.str.replace(pat, repl, n=-1, case=None, flags=0,
> regex=True)[source]**
>
> Replace occurrences of pattern/regex in the
> Series/Index with some other string. Equivalent to str.replace() or
> re.sub(). Parameters:
>
> pat : string or compiled regex
>
> repl : string or callable
> ...

You can correct it using directly the [Pandas.Series.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'descr': ['This: {should be replaced}'],
                   'replacement': 'with this'
                  })
>> df["descr"].replace(r"{.+?}", df["replacement"], regex = True)
0    This: with this
```

**Observation:**

I changed a bit of your regexp.

Comment: You'd better use a `r"{.+?}"` or `r"{[^{}]*}"` pattern.

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew, you are correct! I haven't given so much emphasis on the regexp part. Just edited.

Answer (score 4):

Use list comprehension with `re.sub`, especially if performance is important:

```
import re

df['new'] = [re.sub(r"{.*?}", b, a) for a, b in zip(df['descr'], df['replacement'])]
print (df)
                        descr replacement              new
0  This: {should be replaced}   with this  This: with this
1                This: {data}         aaa        This: aaa
```

Comment: Does leaving pandas for list comprehension have better performance than using pandas.Series.replace ?

Comment: @clstaudt - sure, best test it, `str` operation in pandas are slow.